# Reading IMPI from internal android telephony api

Tags: android, telephony, game-boy-advance

I am trying to read the IMPI from ISIM(required for GBA bootstraping).
I tried the following snippet of code:

```
                Class<?> class1 = Class
                        .forName("com.android.internal.telephony.ims.IsimUiccRecords");
                Object object = class1.newInstance();

                Method method1 = class1.getDeclaredMethod("getIsimImpi");
                System.out.println(method1.invoke(object, null));
```

But call to getIsimImpi(), this way, returns null. I believe, this is due to new instance of IsimUiccRecords, being created, instead of using the appropriate instance (which I am unsure of how to retrive one)

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/ims/IsimUiccRecords.java#IsimUiccRecords) is the link to source of IsimUiccRecords.java

Is is possible at all to retrieve the IMPI, using reflection?

I understand that using internal API might break the code on different versions of android, but it's not a concern for me.

Comment: well, you use reflection way but not Android 4.x API

Comment: @Maxim, why not android 4.X API?

Comment: Every method that doesn't opened for external usage is danger. Most methods I used in the past for Android 4.x do not work. Bear in mind that on other devices it can cause to low level issues. So good practice to use API only and not reflection

Comment: @MaximShoustin Thanks, but it seems reflection is the only way out to get ISIM parameters, though device specific.